# Question about Paramters vs. Variables for Azure CDN

Tags: python, azure

I'm using the Azure python SDK to create CDN origins. There is one parameter I haven't been able to set using the examples given for the SDK. I'm looking at the endpoint class. I'm able to set variables, like 'name' and 'host_name' but not able to set parameters.

I've tried adding the parameters to the api call, but it hasn't worked.

The example code is this:

```py
endpoint_poller = cdn_client.endpoints.create('my-resource-group',
                                          'cdn-name',
                                          'unique-endpoint-name', 
                                          { 
                                              "location": "any_region", 
                                              "origins": [
                                                  {
                                                      "name": "origin_name", 
                                                      "host_name": "url"
                                                  }]
                                          })
```

I have tried adding:

```py
                                               "origins": [
                                                  {
                                                      "name": "origin_name", 
                                                      "host_name": "url",
                                                      "origin_host_header": origin_host
                                                  }]
```

but that did not set the origin_host_header correctly. I'm assuming that since "name" and "host_name" are variables, and "origin_host_header" is a parameter, that simply adding "origin_host_header" to that dict isn't the right place. But I can't find any examples online as to how to properly set parameters.

Without the origin_host_header set, the CDN distribution doesn't work. Once I go in and manually add that to an origin I've added via the API, the CDN starts working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `origin_host_header` is a property of the `EndpointCreateParameters`. Perhaps move it to the same level as the `location` parameter.

```
EndpointCreateParameters:
    location,
    origins,
    tags=None,
    origin_host_header=None,
    origin_path=None,
    content_types_to_compress=None,
    is_compression_enabled=None,
    is_http_allowed=None,
    is_https_allowed=None,
    query_string_caching_behavior=None
```

Comment: Thanks! This was it.